# Risks of cross-compiling proto based library c++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, cross-compiling

I'm trying to isolate a set of .proto definitions, to be used in several other repositories in several languages. So I'd like one repo with .proto files and scripts to export a library for each used language. One of these languages is c++, which is the only compiled language. I'm considering two options:

1. Generate proto.pb.cc and proto.pb.h files and cross-compile it. Export includes/, .lib and .a files
2. Generate proto.pb.cc and proto.pb.h files and export as source. Compile natively in client project.

In order to assess, it would be nice to know some of the risks of cross compilation. How often does this break? Is it an irrational fear for generated files like proto.pb.* ? Typically what kind of c/c++ code breaks when cross compiling?

Comment: By cross-compiling, do you mean "compiling to different architectures"?

Comment: Different OS and different architecture. Windows, Linux and Android. So x86_64 and ARM

Comment: I wouldn't worry about protoc-generated code breaking. It only has dependencies on the corresponding protobuf runtime.